# Understanding the use of medication from EEG

Tags: brain, drug-interactions, seizure

Recently I came across a [study](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HBWzvyPJlqJjI8aeR6ZpIavthceHEs5e/view?usp=sharing) in which a group of people was trying to predict the medication ( especially anticonvulsants like Dilantin and Keppra ) a patient was using from his EEG. Does this have any actual significance in the treatment of epileptic seizures?

Comment: Can you define what "any actual significance" means? Often basic science has influences on treatments that are several steps removed. Not every study is a clinical trial of some treatment.

Comment: @BryanKrause What I meant was, If someone devises an algorithm to understand the type of drug an epileptic seizure patient was using from his EEG ( especially in a situation where the patient is not able to talk ), will that help the doctor in treating the patient.

Comment: @michioKsku That doesn't seem to be their objective. But that's a different question from your title.

Comment: I can't imagine a use for this in direct patient care. Perhaps an ER doc could determine what meds an unconscious seizure patient is taking, but that's unlikely to be an emergent question. Most seizure patients will either be wearing a medic alert tag, carrying a card in their wallet, or have family available to provide that information. It looks to me to be basic science that might be a stepping stone to something more useful in the future. Their focus seems to be a proof of concept in artificial intelligence rather than patient care.